# Adding custom search term into Search Result

Tags: magento-1.9, search, advanced-search

I have a CMS page called "Store Locator" and I noticed a lot of people use the search functionality to search for this page, but Magento search does not index this page since it's not a product or category.

**Is there a way I could add my CMS pages into the search result of Magento?**

Answer (score 1):

With the default search there is no way of doing this without code modification.

Two ideas:

Try another search extension. Magento default isn't good anyway.

Set up a category with this name, no navigation anchor and display a block with your cms content. Delete your old cms page and make redirects via htaccess if needed.